# How to handle unique indexes with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, unique-constraint

The [FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) section of Mongoose 5 explitily says:

> The unique option for schemas is convenient for development and documentation, but mongoose is not an index management solution.

This statement threw me off as I'm relatively new to Mongoose library. I'm making a basic model for `User` and adding a couple of tests for validation. Specifically validate no duplicate users are there.

The schema is simple

```
const schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  ...
```

Needless to say, my test fail:

```
const userA = new User({ email: 'a@a.com' });
const dupUserA = new User({ email: 'a@a.com' });

const promiseChain = userA.save().then(() => dupUserA.save());

expect(promiseChain).to.be.rejected   // using chai-as-promised here
  .then(err => {
    // assertions about error message
  });
```

The test fails cause the promise fulfills, meaning the save was successful.

I don't quite understand what Mongoose team means. I realize these schema are no database "migrations", but since the only example there is in the docs is some callback to the 'index' event, I'm lost.

How should I handle  unique index? Is there a solution not to do them directly to the MongoDB through shell? Something that can reside in the codebase, equivalent to migrations?

Comment: I believe the Mongoose FAQ is trying to clarify that you can declare index options in your models for development purposes, but that Mongoose does not try to ensure that the underlying MongoDB indexes are consistent with your models (i.e. "index management"). For example, if a unique index already exists with different options (same fields, but non-unique), setting the `unique` attribute in your Mongoose model will not recreate the index or ensure uniqueness. Similarly, if you remove unused indexes from your Mongoose models they are not automatically removed from your MongoDB deployment.

Comment: There are quite a few options for Mongoose migrations, but you'll have to do some research into what works best for your use case: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongoose+migrations. These packages tend to work similarly to migration tools for other databases: migration scripts have a unique identifier and predictable processing order so they can be checked into version control and applied once per database environment. Custom logic can usually be added with promises or callbacks.